# input type="submit" doesn't show full text

Tags: html, django, forms, input

and I have a list of element {{FieldName}}.

when I use this list inside an input it shows just the first Word not all text?

my code

```
              {% for con2 in FieldName %}
    <table style="border-width: 2px; border: #333;"><tr>
    <input type="submit" value= {{con2.FidlAbr}}  name="FieldName" style="width:200px;"></tr></table>
    {% endfor %}</form>
          </div></div></div>
```

the output should be like:
BEQ ,
HMZ ,
TFT DEVO 100 ,
TIM SNAGUENE ,
TFNW ,
TRNW

but it gave me an output like!!

BEQ ,
HMZ ,
TFT,
TIM,
TFNW ,
TRNW

what is the problem with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put apostrophes around it, just like the other attributes, so instead of

```
<input type="submit" value= {{con2.FidlAbr}}  name="FieldName" ...
```

you need

```
<input type="submit" value="{{con2.FidlAbr}}"  name="FieldName" ...
```